# Please VTD "questions" that are blog posts about Covid-19

Tags: discussion, questions

I won't name a particular user here, although I do have one in mind as the prime example, but as general note: some users turn their questions (sometimes after they are answered) into [fairly long] blog posts  letting us know their opinions on this-and-that issue related to the Covid-19 epidemic. Please vote to delete such "questions". Getting into a rollback war with the OP is generally not worth the hassle as such questions are generally of low quality to begin with.

As I didn't have saved links to the (thankfully, quickly) deleted older questions, I'll show you one for a more [recently posted one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52406/should-the-us-government-and-boeing-be-more-transparent-before-any-bailout-is-de) (as requested in a comment below). Although it's not as weird as the old questions were, it's still a rhetorical question at best:

> Shouldn't the government (or Congress) before taking any decision impose more transparency and let them make public some more details?

See also [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/52362/18373) which calls downvoters "trolls"; I have flagged the latter, so it may be gone soon.

Comment: Oftentimes all it takes for garbage to get mass-downvoted and deleted is for someone to raise it on meta. I just went through the covid-19 tagged questions and no user stood out as regularly having heavily downvoted questions in the past week. As to the downvoted questions none seemed to be long blog posts. Given this, it would be helpful if you actually named the offending user(s) you've in mind, and/or provided a few links to questions (or answers) as examples. Also, there are VtC and flags.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: see edit

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: oh, the irony, I see *you* actually answered that question (well with a frame challenge). That was more or less the same issue with the old questions from the same user (people generally answered them by challenging the premises), except the OP edited them afterwards to add more lengthy thoughts. Also, please *don't edit* questions like that as you did [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/52406/2) because they get auto-renominated for reopening.

Answer (score 4):

Better idea: flag for a moderator. They are much better equipped to handle these types of situations.

If the content is bad, then yes it should be closed and deleted. But this is independent of the OP starting an edit war. If you think the question is worthwhile, is should be kept, even if the OP is trying to start an edit war.

Please, don't delete good content.

Comment: @Chipster moderators and other high rep users can see deleted content in the mod overview. The posts and edits I think Fizz is referring to are about making a point regarding the responses to the virus outbreak in different countries. At first and when considered individually, I wouldn't delete them because it could be an honest question (though not in the numbers I've seen). Then, if the edits keep changing the posts to further push a view point it's off-topic and worth deleting.

Comment: Whether such posts may be worth flagging as well is a different question. If the behavior persists, I agree that it's a worthwhile option. In practice, however, it doesn't take that many downvotes, closures, deletions and other flags for the user to be sanctioned automatically and for mods to become aware of the situation.